# How can my app appear in mobile safari URL bar as a app store suggestion (like slack)?

Tags: safari, app-store, mobile-safari, slack, search-suggestion

What technical requirements or methods do I need to implement to make my app appear in the URL browser under "app Store" suggestions in safari? This is what happens if I am typing in "slack" straight into the url bar of safari. It also appears if I haven't installed slack at all --> that's what I would like to implement as well.

Is that a auto suggestion-tool by safari which we can not influence at all?

Any hints to make that happen? Here's an image of Slack on Safari:

[image: Image of Slack on safari]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These suggestions are known as Safari or Siri Suggestions, and appear to be controlled solely by Apple/Safari itself.

[One source on Quora says](https://www.quora.com/How-are-Suggested-Websites-chosen-in-Safari/answer/Jason-Douglas-58),

> “Siri Suggested Websites” are search results that come directly from Apple’s own search engine, based on websites they’ve crawled and indexed. It’s not based on your search history (or even anything you’ve done with Siri).

I wonder if your app would show up as a Suggestion if it was unique or popular enough in Apple's search indices...